# How to install ubuntu ia a touch screen laptop

Tags: touchscreen

Can ubuntu be install in a touch screen laptop. I has try few time but still cannot install it. I install it using bootable usb drive.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen) page? Maybe you have another problem... Are there any error messages during installation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the live CD? If that works, then installing it should be possible too. At least, it should not be the touch screen posing problems...

If you cannot install or even run the live CD, it might be because of UEFI with Secure Boot enabled on the device. Search the net for your device and if it has UEFI with Secure Boot enabled by default and find instructions on how to disable Secure Boot from within Windows.